# Create new builder using com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.Descriptor

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I need to create newBuilder() of a class for a given com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.Descriptor.

I have created a jar using google proto buffer for the following protocol :

```
message Foo
{
  optional uint32 id = 1;
  optional string fooName = 2;
}
message Bar
{
  optional uint32 id = 1;
  optional string barName = 2;
}
```

From Java side, based on Descriptor I need to create newBuilder().
For example :

```
    Message.Builder message;
    if(Descriptor.getName().equals("Foo"))
        message = Foo.newBuilder();
    if(Descriptor.getName().equals("Bar"))
        message = Bar.newBuilder();
```

But I don't want to go for if else or switch case.
Also I have tried some other way using DynamicMessage.

```
Message.Builder message = DynamicMessage.newBuilder(descriptor);
```

But in this case I am not able to cast it into **Foo** or **Bar** class. Is there any other way to create newBuilder() using Descriptor or Descriptor name?

Blindly I need newBuilder() of given class name like this :

```
Message.Builder message = SomeUtilClass.getNewBuilder("Foo");
```

Comment: I tend to find that it's easier to pass around `Foo.getDefaultInstance()` rather than its descriptor; then you can get both its builder and its descriptor.

Comment: Actually my issue is that I am not having actual Foo or Bar there. I have only Descriptor of Foo or Bar. Using that Descriptor I need to create new builder. Currently we are creating new builder using if else condition. I want to minimize the code.

Comment: Right. And I'm saying: if you can, don't pass a Descriptor, pass the default instance of the proto instead, because it a) has more type information; b) lets you get the descriptor and a builder. Your design - that you pass the Descriptor - makes it harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Yes my need is to create a builder from Descriptor or any other fields of Descriptor. To avoid if else or switch. Because we have more classes like Foo,Bar

Answer (score 5):

You can't create a `Builder` from a `Descriptor`. A `Descriptor` has no type information as to the proto (or builder) class that it need to create, because all `Descriptor` instances are of the same class ([it's final](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.Descriptor)).

If you can only work with the `Descriptor`, your `if/else` is roughly as good as you can get. (I say roughly because you could do it with a map or a switch instead; but it's basically the same).

A better approach would be to work with the default instance of the proto that you are trying to create (or any other instance of that proto; but the default instance is simplest to obtain).

```
Message prototype = Foo.getDefaultInstance();  // Or Bar.getDefaultInstance().
```

because from [`Message`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Message) you can get both a builder and the descriptor:

```
Message.Builder builder = prototype.newBuilderForType();
Descriptor descriptor = prototype.getDescriptorForType();
```

Comment: Ok will try with DefaultInstance.

Comment: Blindly I need newBuilder() of given class name like this 
Message.Builder message = SomeUtilClass.getNewBuilder("Foo");

Comment: Then `SomeUtilClass.getNewBuilder` needs an if/else chain like you currently have; or a switch; or a map. That's even worse than having only the `Descriptor`.

Comment: Ok no issues will move our if else to some util. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: BTW: use `getFullName()`, not `getName()`, to avoid name collisions.